# Image is not increasing in height when set

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a logo in html with the following code:

```html
<div class="company-logo">
   <img src="images\teia.PNG" alt="company-logo" style="height:100px;"/>
</div>
```

The width of the image is increasing when I set width. But when I am trying to increase the height, whatever height I set, it is not increasing.

What could be the problem?

Comment: It's probably limited by .company-logo height in your .css file...

Comment: What if you try adding `!important` to the image style?

Comment: Open the debugger in your browser, select your image element from the `Elements` tab. In the bottom right, you can see three tabs, select `Styles` tab--> It will show all the applied css of that element. If you see a `height` property with a `strike-through`, it means that the particular style is being overridden at a different level.

Comment: @chaska how do i do it

Comment: style="height:100px !important;", but I wouldn't do that, it's a bad practice to mark a property as important. It overrides other parts of code and might make it very difficult to read.

Comment: Your code is basically working: https://jsfiddle.net/dxako9g1/ there is something else going on we are not aware of. What styles are being applied to `.company-logo`? Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Juat set the ***parent div***'s ***height width*** as per your *requirement* and give style to the ***child img*** element of ***height 100%*** and ***width 100%***.

```css
.company-logo {
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
}

.company-logo > img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="company-logo">
  <img src="https://www.stoodnt.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/dummy.jpg" alt="company-logo" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<div class="company-logo">
   <img src="images\teia.PNG" alt="company-logo" height="42" width="42"/>
</div>
```

Comment: @harmonica141 its not about syntax, i have tried the correct syntax also. its about the paraent div